# Lock Screen & Dock Bug

Tags: bug-reporting

There appears to be a bug with both of my machines running Ubuntu 18.04 with latest updates. I've seen this bug posted elsewhere, but I can't seem to find the post again.

When I lock my machine it does not actually lock the device. I have to press the lock command a second time in order for the device to actually lock. Then once locked, the dock which shouldn't be on the lock screen, is visible and clickable.

[image: lockscreen]

So the device basically is locked, but not locked entirely. Which in my opinion is a HUGE security risk.

Second the dock itself does not auto-hide like it should. Instead it stays visible over top of all windows, even when the windows are maximized, which is extremely inconvenient especially when trying to use apps like photoshop fullscreen.

Also turning auto-hide off on the dock settings does not make the window manager aware of this and the dock still appears above maximized windows, rather than to the side of the the windows.

[image: desktop with dock over photoshop]

Normally I would think this is specific to my machine, but this is happening on two different computers of mine. I also know I have seen this reported somewhere else.

I am worried about the security issue as one of my systems is a business device. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1769383 Restarting GNOME shell (by pressing <Alt><F2>, then entering `r` and finally pressing <Enter>) would probably solve the issue temporarily.